# How to escape xml content in a raw string?

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting a string of 'xml' that contains some content that is unescaped. Here is a trivial example:

```
<link text="This is some text with "potentially" some quoted text in it." linktype="external" anchor="" target="" />
```

The problem I have is when you try to convert the above as a string using `XmlDocument.LoadXml()`, `LoadXml()` throws an exception because of the lack of escaping on the inner quotes for the content held by attribute 'text'. Is there a relatively painless way to escape the content specifically? Or am I just going to have to parse it/escape it/rebuild it myself?

i'm not generating this text, i just get it from another process in a string like this:

```
"<link text="This is some text with "potentially" some quoted text in it." linktype="external" anchor="" target="" />"
```

Comment: I'd see about getting whatever generates that XML to generate _compliant_ XML first. This is not something that you should have to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the html character encoding where `"` is `&quot;`

But since your input is a malformed xml text you have to find a way to parse that text and replace the quotes with their encoded translation. Maybe some regex parsing..

Please consider this just a creative way to make the job. I know it's dirty but it will work in most cases:

```
 private static string XmlEncodeQuotes(string target) {

        string result = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < target.Length; i++)
        {
            if (target[i] == '"')
            {
                if (target[i - 1] != '=')
                    if (!Regex.IsMatch(target.Substring(i), @"^""\s[a-zA-Z]+="""))
                    {
                        result += "&quot;";
                        continue;
                    }
            }
            result += target[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: yeah, i'm hoping there is a less painless way to do this built into .NET already before i start trying to write regex's to clean it up...

Comment: actually I think it's pretty impossible otherwise because if you start thinking about the regex you'll see you need lots of blind guessing

Comment: this is actually pretty close to what I need, just had to do a minor tweak to handle the regex matching an ending quote of an empty attribute (like: 'id=""').

Answer (score 0):

have you tried wrapping the portion of the xml document within a CDATA tag?

Comment: i'm not generating the content, so i can't just change the process generating the above string, if that's what you mean. i'm literally getting the content above in a string and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Will System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape() work for you?  If not, there is an XmlTextWriter as well.

Comment: I'm not downvoting but no! it will NOT work! it will just translate ANY "invalid" character

Comment: OK, I reread it and I thought you were looking to write the value you received into a different XML file, but if you are looking to parse it and it is invalid then you likely either need to parse it yourself or get the provider of the data to send you properly escaped XML snippets, depending on how restricted the extent of what kinds of snippets you are sent (i.e. if they are always this "link" style one then self parsing is easy enough).

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply asking how to escape a quote, that's done with

```
&quot;
```

I'm not sure what you're dealing with, but the root of your problem is the fact that the data you are receiving is malformed.

- Option 1) Unless you clean up the data, you will have a hard time getting most parsers to load invalid XML data. Some are more forgiving than others. You might have some luck with the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)
- Option 2) [Use Regular Expressions to fix your XML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798781/using-regex-to-fix-xml-content)
- Option 3) If coding a parsing solution is not an option use XSLT. Simply create   transform and then add a template to fix the issues.